# Can't FTP into Google Compute Engine instance using Debian

Tags: debian, vsftpd

After trying to setup vsftpd on my google compute engine instance, I was unable to completely connect to the FTP server. After attempting to login with FileZilla, I got this response:

```
Status: Connecting to ***.***.***.***:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 (vsFTPd 2.3.5)
Command:    USER anonymous
Response:   331 Please specify the password.
Command:    PASS **************
Response:   230 Login successful.
Command:    SYST
Response:   215 UNIX Type: L8
Command:    FEAT
Response:   211-Features:
Response:    EPRT
Response:    EPSV
Response:    MDTM
Response:    PASV
Response:    REST STREAM
Response:    SIZE
Response:    TVFS
Response:    UTF8
Response:   211 End
Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Response:   200 Always in UTF8 mode.
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/"
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Switching to Binary mode.
Command:    PASV
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

Please note that this is a completely fresh install of vsftpd.

Comment: have you tried another ftp client ? this clearly shows that the server cannot go into passive mode: `Command:    PASV`

Answer (score 6):

The solution is to limit the ports that vsftpd allocates for PASV style data connections in the configuration file. In the vsftpd.conf, add those two lines:

> pasv_min_port=12000
>
> pasv_max_port=12100

Then you will need to open those ports in the Google Developers Console, under Networking, Firewall rules (see image).

[image]

You also might want to add the following line to override the IP address that vsftpd advertises in response to the PASV command:

> pasv_address=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

You put the External IP of your VM instance.

I also use FTP port 211 instead of 21 for security reasons:

> listen_port=211

Answer (score 3):

Seem that google computer engine already have SFTP service by default.  Following is an excellent step by step instruction to use WinSCP as SFTP client to connect to the service. It works perfectly for me on first try.

http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_google_compute_engine

Same principle should apply to use other FTP client software.
Hope will save some one time and effort.